# Sum of nested values in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I'm starting with definitions similar to these below

```
sig Sub { vals : set Int }
sig Top { subs : set Sub }
```

I'd like an expression that can produce the sum of all values contained inside something of type `Top`. `Top` when written as a nested set, would be something like `{{3, 4}, {7}}`. The result of the nested sum in this case should be 14.

This function of course just gives the number of elements in the outer set.

```
fun allsum[t: Top] : one Int { #t }
```

I believe I need to use the built-in `sum` function and a set comprehension, but Alloy syntax is still somewhat arcane to me.

Comment: A set does not allow duplicates. Do you need to allow duplicate Int's between Top's?

Comment: @PeterKriens I understand sets can't have duplicates. I would want to allow something like `{{3, 4}, {3}`, but that shouldn't a problem since each subset is unique. I may want to allow something like `{{3}, {3}}` in the future, but that seems unrelated to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you need a nested sum expression:

```
fun allsum[t: Top] : Int { 
    sum s: t.subs | (sum v: s.vals | v)
}
```

The general format is:

```
sum e: <set> | <expression involving e>
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I need :)