# How to sum more than two numbers in Alloy Analyzer?

Tags: alloy, model-checking

I am trying to sum all the numbers in a set in Alloy.
For instance, in the signature **abc**, I want the value to be the sum of a.value + b.value + c.value, which is 4+1+3=8.

However, if I use **"+"**, it gives me the union set and not the sum.

PS. I know there is the **"plus"** (as I used it in **sig sumab**), but this only allows me to sum two values.

Thanks

```js
open util/integer

sig a{value: Int}
{
value = 4
}
sig b{value: Int}
{
value = 1
}
sig c{value: Int}
{
value = 3
}
sig abc{value: set Int}
{
    value = a.value + b.value + c.value
}

sig sumab{
    value : Int
}
{
value = plus[a.value, b.value]
}

pred add{}

run add for 4 int, exactly 1 sumab, exactly 1 a, exactly 1 b, exactly 1 c, exactly 1 abc
```

Note: I wrote this in pseudo-code, it may help to get to an answer:

```
fun plusN [setInt : set de Int] : Int {  // function "plusN" should take a set of integers "setInt", return an integer
    if #setInt = 2  //if only two numbers in set, sum them
            then plus[max setInt , min setInt]
    else // if more than 2, use recursion
            plusN [max setInt  , plusN[{setInt - max setInt}]]
}
```

Note 2. The function **sum** may seem to be a good idea, but if I sum 1+1+1=1, the result will be 1 intead of 3 as the only number in the set is 1.

Comment: Why are you trying to sum values in a set?  If you could give us some context of what you're trying to accomplish it may help us to suggest a technique that would work for you.

Comment: I have a set of tasks, each with different costs; and a set of processing units with a maximum cost they can handle. For each generated model, I am summing the cost of the tasks allocated to each processing unit so that it doesn't exceed its capacity. Thanks.

Comment: Ok--so are you sure Alloy is the right tool to solve your issue?

Comment: Well, I can get allocations of tasks to processing units. My problem is when I try to get the tasks' cost sum of each processing units between a bandwidth. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean to say is that the problem you’re solving (if I am understanding you correctly) seems sort of concrete—not abstract at all. Hence I wonder if Alloy is the right tool for your purposes.

Comment: I believe the costs are fixed for each process unit. However, I am describing how the tasks are allocated depending on the heterogeneous characteristics of the tasks. The output of the alloy analyzer gives me possible feasible allocations given the set of facts. I believe this is a fair problem to be solved by contraint solvers, but that's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Alloy comes with a built-in `sum` function, so just do `sum[value]`.

Comment: I tried again with my actual application and it didn't work. It works if the numbers are different sum[{1,2,3}]=6, but not when they are the same, for example: a.value= 1 , b.value= 1 and c.value= 1, sum[a.value, b.value, c.value]=1, as the set only contains 1.

Comment: This is what I did: ``` sig a{value: set Int} { value = {int 1 + int 2 + int 3} } sig suma{ value : Int } {value = sum[a.value] } pred add{} run add for 5 int, exactly 1 suma, exactly 1 a```

Comment: If you can't pass the same value twice to the sum function because each element of a set are unique, you could enforce each value integers to be disjoint. It's dirty but it will make your model work. If you need to justify the use of disjoint, you could say that it is because of the aforementioned Alloy limitation

Comment: Could you show how to do this, please? If I create something like: fact{disj [a.value,b.value]}, where a.value and b.value are the same int, there are no models found (understandably).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035050/4228052), Alloy has a `sum` keyword (different than the `sum` function) which can be used.

> The general format is:
>
> ```
> sum e: <set> | <expression involving e>
> ```

## Variable sig values

Here's a simple example that sums the number of sales during a day for a restaurant's three meals. In particular, note the use of the `sum` keyword in `fun sum_sales`.

```
one sig Restaurant { total_sales: Int }
abstract sig Meal { sales: Int }
one sig Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner in Meal {}

// Each meal only falls in one category
fact { disj[Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner] }
// Every meal is in some category
fact { Breakfast + Lunch + Dinner = Meal }

// Keep the numbers small because the max alloy int is 7
fact { all m: Meal | m.sales <= 4 }
// Negative sales don't make sense
fact { all m: Meal | m.sales >= 0 }

fun sum_sales: Int { sum m: Meal | m.sales }
fact { Restaurant.total_sales = sum_sales }
```

This works even when all meals have the same number of sales (`1 + 1 + 1 = 3`), as shown in this `check`.

```
check { (all m: Meal | m.sales = 1) => Restaurant.total_sales = 3 }
```

Here are some other ways to play around with the example.

```
check {
    {
        // One meal with three sales
        #{ m: Meal | m.sales = 3 } = 1
        // Two meals with one sale
        #{ m: Meal | m.sales = 1 } = 2
    } => Restaurant.total_sales = 5
}

run { Restaurant.total_sales = 5 }
```

## Constant sig values

Another way you might want to use this is to have the value associated with each type of `Meal` be constant, but allow the number of `Meal`s to vary. You can model this with a relation mapping each meal type to a number of sales as follows.

```
one sig Restaurant { total_sales: Int }
abstract sig Meal {}
lone sig Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner in Meal {}

// Each meal only falls in one category
fact { disj[Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner] }
// Every meal is in some category
fact { Breakfast + Lunch + Dinner = Meal }

fun meal_sales: Meal -> Int {
    Breakfast -> 2
    + Lunch -> 2
    + Dinner -> 3
}

fun sum_sales: Int { sum m: Meal | m.meal_sales }
fact { Restaurant.total_sales = sum_sales }

check { #Meal = 3 => Restaurant.total_sales = 6 }
run { Restaurant.total_sales = 5 }
```